# Having trouble viewing more than 10 rows in a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble, tidytext

First off - I am a beginner at programming and R, so excuse me if this is a silly question. I am having trouble viewing more than ten rows in a tibble that is generated from the following code.

The code below is meant to find the most common words in a book. I am getting the results I want, but how do I view more than 10 rows of data. To my knowledge, it is not being saved as a data frame that I can call.

```
library(dplyr)
tidy_books %>%
    anti_join(stop_words) %>%
    count(word, sort=TRUE)
Joining, by = "word"
# A tibble: 3,397 x 2
   word       n
   <chr>  <int>
 1 alice    820
 2 queen    247
 3 time     141
 4 king     122
 5 head     112
 6 looked   100
 7 white     97
 8 round     96
 9 voice     86
10 tone      81
# ... with 3,387 more rows
```

Comment: Try `View(tidy_boooks)` or `head(tidy_books, 20)`

Comment: tibbles intentionally only print a few rows - you can send the result through `%>% print(n = 20)` to see more.

Comment: The suggestion by @Marius is probably the most elegant, however you can also simply wrap your entire statement with `as.data.frame`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I often do when I want to see the output of a pipe like that is pipe it straight to `View()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

tidy_books %>%
    anti_join(stop_words) %>%
    count(word, sort=TRUE) %>%
    View()
```

If you want to save this to a new object that you can work with later, you can assign it to a new variable name at the beginning of the pipe.

```
word_counts <- tidy_books %>%
    anti_join(stop_words) %>%
    count(word, sort=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 30):

Although this question has a perfectly ok answer, the comment from @Marius is much shorter, so:

```
tidy_books %>% print(n = 100)
```

As you say you are a beginner you can replace `n = 100` with any number you want

Also as you are a beginner, to see the whole table:

```
tidy_books %>% print(n = nrow(tidy_books))
```

Comment: for some reason, `print(n = ...)` turns on scientific notation in the tibble display. is there away to avoid that?

Comment: You can do `options(scipen=10)` to penalize the display of scientific notation. Higher numbers penalize (and thus reduce) the chance of scientific notation being displayed, lower numbers (like -10) increase the chance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in the console, then note that tibbles have print S3 methods defined so you can use options such as (see `?print.tbl`):

```
very_long <- as_tibble(seq(1:1000))
print(very_long, n = 3)
# A tibble: 1,000 x 1
  value
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
# ... with 997 more rows
```

Note, `tail` doesn't play with tibbles, so if you want to combine `tail` with tibbles to look at the end of your data, then you have to do something like:

```
print(tail(very_long, n = 3), n = 3)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  value
  <int>
1   998
2   999
3  1000
```